# WebServices and Web Application in the same IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

This is a very silly question, but I am begginer on this subject so: 
If an Application A (asp.net MVC C application) is hosted in the same machine and IIS of WebServices B, is it possible that A consume B by using IP instead of URL? 
If yes, Is this behavior configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and very simple. Just go ahead and use the IP when specifying the address on your Application A. You can even use 127.0.0.1 and it should work.

However, if both your applications (asp.net mvc and webservices) are bound to port 80 and differ only on the host, you will need to create an entry in the local HOSTS file pointing to the local IP in order to make it work.

Comment: Great, thank you! Is it a good pratice to optimize the access for local applications?

Comment: If both applications (web services and web app) are in the same box, why not? Of course one can argue why they are in the same and maybe find out that they should not be together. But if they are there is no reason you need to leave the machine to respond to the request. Also, like mentioned by @Mike Goodwin, if you are using WCF you should expose a netNamedPipe which is built exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible. If your service is SOAP based (basicHttpBining, wsHttpBinding etc.) you could consider using netNamedPipe binding instead.

This is optimised for inter-process communication on the same machine.

It doesn't impact your service code, so if you split onto two servers in the future, it will just be a config change.